# noindex all posts and doindex all tags

Tags: seo, google-search, duplicate-content, blog, noindex

I have a Tumblr-style picture blog running on WordPress. 
The blog has **only one picture per post**, and thousands of pics all tagged.

Let's pretend its all pics of cars; each post has one pic of a car, and a tag with the make/model of the car.
From a user point of view, I think a user that would search for "1990 Mustang pics" for example, would be best off to find my tag page (`example.com/tag/fordmustang1990`). This page has hundreds of 1990 Ford Mustang pics.

But Google is mainly **ranking my posts**, so a user would usually land on just a post with one Mustang pic; not to mention most of these Mustang **posts have the same title** creating a bunch of **duplicate content** (creating unique titles for the thousands of posts is not realistic).

**Would it be a viable option to set all posts to noindex, and just index all the tags** and pages only? I could say include a short intro text at the top of each tag page (heres a bunch of Mustang pics, bla bla).

My site has been around for a few years and some of the posts rank ok, so I'm a little chicken to experiment and have all these unindexed.

Anyone have any experience, knowledge they could share?